# Appending blank rows to dataframe if column does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This question is kind of odd and complex, so bear with me, please.

I have several massive CSV files (GB size) that I am importing with `pandas`.  These CSV files are dumps of data collected by a data acquisition system, and I don't need most of it, so I'm using the `usecols` parameter to filter out the relevant data.  The issue is that not all of the CSV files have all of the columns I need (a property of the data system being used).

The problem is that, if the column doesn't exist in the file but is specified in `usecols`, `read_csv` throws an error.

Is there a straightforward way to force a specified column set in a dataframe and have `pandas` just return blank rows if the column doesn't exist?  I thought about iterating over each column for each file and working the resulting series into the dataframe, but that seems inefficient and unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about iterating over each column for each file and working the resulting series into the dataframe, but that seems inefficient and unwieldy.

Assuming some kind of master list `all_cols_to_use`, can you do something like:

```
def parse_big_csv(csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, 'r') as infile:
        header = infile.readline().strip().split(',')
        cols_to_use = sorted(set(header) & set(all_cols_to_use))
        missing_cols = sorted(set(all_cols_to_use) - set(header))
    df = pd.read_csv(csvpath, usecols=cols_to_use)
    df.loc[:, missing_cols] = np.nan
    return df
```

This assumes that you're okay with filling the missing columns with `np.nan`, but should work. (Also, if you’re concatenating the data frames, the missing columns will be in the final df and filled with `np.nan` as appropriate.)

Comment: I do have a fixed list of columns that are either present or not (they don't move, they just don't exist because the system isn't initialized yet).

`np.nan` isn't a problem, because the end result is a plot so that just won't get plotted.

I don't follow your parenthetical - you're saying that, in a concatenated data frame, any rows that would be "blank" due to the column not existing for that file will be filled with `np.nan`, right?

Comment: If you concatenate df1 and df2,  where df1 has column A and dg2 doesn't, the resultant dataframe will have column A and all of the values for df2 will be nans.