# Pandas make row blank if header does not exist

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to combine multiple excel files with Python Pandas. Some files have different headers from each other:

[Similar question on stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126726/appending-blank-rows-to-dataframe-if-column-does-not-exist?rq=1)

This is where it fails:

```py
# Turn them into dataframes using pandas
frames = []
for excel in excels:
  frame = excel.parse(excel.sheet_names[0],index_col=None)
  frames.append(frame[['Charges', 'Amount','Taxes','Date','Discount Percent', 'Zipcode', 'Order Number']])
```

> KeyError: "['Charges', 'Zipcode', 'Discount Percent'] not in index"

One excel file might have a header but another doesn't and this part of the code fails, how can I make it so if it encounters a header that is not present to just keep going or make the field blank?

The entire script:
**concat.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

excel_path = "C:\\Users\\khernandez\\Desktop\\compare-and-concat\\raw\\"
# File names to join
excel_names = [excel_path + f for f in os.listdir('./raw')]

excels = []
for name in excel_names:
  print("Loading File: " + name)
  excels.append(pd.ExcelFile(name))

# Turn them into dataframes using pandas
frames = []
for excel in excels:
  print("Converting to data frame")
  print(excel)
  frame = excel.parse(excel.sheet_names[0],index_col=None)
  frames.append(frame[['Charges', 'Amount','Taxes','Date','Discount Percent', 'Zipcode', 'Order Number']])


# # Delete the first row of the excel file
# print("Removing HEADERS")
# frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# Combine the dataframes
print("Combining frames")
combined = pd.concat(frames)


# Write them out to a file named concated.xlsx
combined.to_excel("concated.xlsx", header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing this in the blind and not fully tested.

You have a fixed set of columns to extract from source Excel files. Use `intersection` to get only those that exist, then `index` to add back the missing columns (if any):

```
frames = []
cols = ['Charges', 'Amount','Taxes','Date','Discount Percent', 'Zipcode', 'Order Number']
for excel in excels:
    ...
    frames.append(frame[np.intersect1d(cols, frame.columns.values)])

combined = pd.concat(frames, sort=False, ignore_index=True) \
                .reindex(cols, axis=0)
```

Comment: Mirrored your code into mines, `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'` I looked up the documentation. It seems to be right why isnt it working then?

Comment: Sorry, my failure at reading documentation. Changed to `np.intersect1d`

Comment: The script runs but only prints out the headers to my excel file, maybe something in `pd.concat()`?

Comment: I just removed everything but `sort=False` and it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I though it was the `axis` value in `reindex`